# Embedded association not being persisted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I've followed [this tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association?view=asciicast) for the exact same use case of assigning roles to users.

I'm using `Rails 3.2.16`.

When I try testing role assignment from the pry console I get that the `roles` field of `User` is not updated.

here's the pry text:

```
[14] pry(main)> a = User.last
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 7, email: "a@b.c", encrypted_password: "...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2013-12-29 11:14:36", last_sign_in_at: "2013-12-29 11:14:36", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2013-12-29 11:14:04", updated_at: "2013-12-31 09:50:26", username: "asf", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2013-12-29 11:14:26", confirmation_sent_at: "2013-12-29 11:14:04", unconfirmed_email: nil, roles_mask: 0>
[15] pry(main)> a.roles = [:admin, :expired]
=> [:admin, :expired]
[16] pry(main)> a.save
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

Here's the relating methods from the model:

```
ROLES = %w[admin active expired]

  def roles=(roles)
    self.roles_mask = (roles & ROLES).map { |r| 2**ROLES.index(r) }.sum
  end

  def roles
    ROLES.reject { |r| ((roles_mask || 0) & 2**ROLES.index(r)).zero? }
  end

  def role_symbols
    roles.map(&:to_sym)
  end
```

and here's the migration:

```
class AddRolesMaskToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :roles_mask, :integer
  end
end
```

Would you know why the association is not persisted here?

thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Just a comment, check `(roles & ROLES)`. You're intersecting a string array with a symbol array. Will return empty array?

Comment: yep, indeed I figured the solution already, I was lucky: you exactly got spot on. I converted ROLES into an array of symbols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that I was matching strings with symbols in the `roles=` method and this would not work.

I've converted everything to symbols now, and it works nicely.

Here's the new code:

```
  ROLES = [:admin, :active, :expired]

  def roles=(roles)
    self.roles_mask= (roles & ROLES).map { |r| 2**ROLES.index(r) }.sum
  end

  def roles
    roles_symbols.reject { |r| ((roles_mask || 0) & 2**ROLES.index(r)).zero? }
  end
```